# Problem with a simple layout in Flutter, just 3 elements below each other, without using MaterialApp

Tags: flutter

In flutter I am trying to build a very basic thing. Three elements on top of each other and vertically centered, like this:

[image]

I don't want to use MaterialApp, so my code for now is this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
      child: Row(children: [
        Column(
          children: const <Widget>[Text('ELE1')],
        ),
        Column(
          children: const <Widget>[Text('ELE2')],
        ),
        Column(
          children: const <Widget>[Text('ELE3')],
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

But I am getting an error:

> ErrorSummary('No Directionality widget found.'),

Which is odd because I thought a column could be contained in a row which in turn could be contained in a container, no ?

Comment: any reason you dont need to use material app

Comment: Actually, the `Text` widget causes directionality error. Wrap your widget tree with a `Directionality` widet and give it textDirection to get rid of that error.

Comment: @MrShakila could you please tell me the most obvious reason why I would need it ?

Comment: @ailauli69 MaterialApp Widget is the starting point of your app, it tells Flutter that you are going to use Material components and follow the material design in your app.

Comment: @MrShakila but what is the interest of using Material designs ?

Comment: @MrShakila and if I would use Material design, how would you set this simple layout ?

Comment: i added answer check that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to use MaterailApp this is how you use it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}


class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text('ELE1'),
                Text('ELE1'),
                Text('ELE1')
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, could you please tell me how to take the full width ?

Comment: what is the widget that you need to get full width

Answer (score 1):

`Rows` are horizontal, `Columns` vertical. Just replacing that `Row` with a `Column` might do the trick for you, but it also it doesn't make sense to have each `Text` wrapped in its own `Column`. So just replace

```
Row(children: [
    Column(
      children: const <Widget>[Text('ELE1')],
    ),
    Column(
      children: const <Widget>[Text('ELE2')],
    ),
    Column(
      children: const <Widget>[Text('ELE3')],
    ),
  ]),
```

with

```
Column(children: [Text('ELE1'), Text('ELE2'), Text('ELE3')]),
```